# Tensorflow appears to install but does not actually work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have installed tensor flow as follows:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

(as well as adding the following that worked when trying to troubleshoot that also executed without error):

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0.0
```

when I open up a jupiter notebook and type:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I don't get an error thrown however when I try to take the next step and do

```
tf.Session()
```

it throws me the following error (cut part of it out to fit the message, but it seems repetitive everywhere):

```
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1806, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1090, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 311, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 345, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 1480, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 1438, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 693, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 730, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v2/audio/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_audio_ops.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1806, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1806, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2802, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2879, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1809, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1371, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1279, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1140, in structured_traceback
    formatted_exceptions += self.prepare_chained_exception_message(evalue.__cause__)
TypeError: must be str, not list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1806, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1090, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 311, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 345, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 1480, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 1438, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 693, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 730, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v2/audio/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_audio_ops.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-30-e18415998e60>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v2/audio/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_audio_ops.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1806, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 

ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in showtraceback(self, exc_tuple, filename, tb_offset, exception_only, running_compiled_code)
   1805                         # in the engines. This should return a list of strings.
-> 1806                         stb = value._render_traceback_()
   1807                     except Exception:

AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_code(self, code_obj, result)
   2877             if result is not None:
   2878                 result.error_in_exec = sys.exc_info()[1]
-> 2879             self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
   2880         else:
   2881             outflag = False

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in showtraceback(self, exc_tuple, filename, tb_offset, exception_only, running_compiled_code)
   1807                     except Exception:
   1808                         stb = self.InteractiveTB.structured_traceback(etype,
-> 1809                                             value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
   1810 
   1811                     self._showtraceback(etype, value, stb)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py in structured_traceback(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1369         self.tb = tb
   1370         return FormattedTB.structured_traceback(
-> 1371             self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1372 
   1373 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py in structured_traceback(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1277             # Verbose modes need a full traceback
   1278             return VerboseTB.structured_traceback(
-> 1279                 self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
   1280             )
   1281         else:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py in structured_traceback(self, etype, evalue, etb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1138             exception = self.get_parts_of_chained_exception(evalue)
   1139             if exception:
-> 1140                 formatted_exceptions += self.prepare_chained_exception_message(evalue.__cause__)
   1141                 etype, evalue, etb = exception
   1142             else:

TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Comment: If you're using Anaconda/Conda, why install TensorFlow with pip?

Answer (score 0):

The code
`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

installs pip for your system globally. You can confirm this by creating a .py file anywhere, and writing the following code below,
`import tensorflow as tf`

you can also test it by running 'python' in a shell, then running the above command.

## About pip

It should be noted that there is a stark difference between using pip and using anaconda. pip is a '[package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager)' for Python, a CLI tool for setting up packages from the [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/pip/).

You can use pip for setting up packages either locally as a repo on a filesystem on your machine, or you can install those packages as globally ( install once, run anywhere on your machine ). Certain disadvantages occur when installing globally. For the, 'virtualenv' is used. Please consult [the python doc](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) for help.

## About Conda

It's a package manager mostly used for data science projects, mostly comes along with Anaconda, the GUI provider for Jupyter and Spyder notebooks. See [anaconda here](https://www.anaconda.com/).

## The confusion

Jupyter notebooks use a conda 'virtual environment', you're assuming that Jupyter will be able to pick up packages that you install using pip, which is not the case.

## The Solution Is To Make A Conda Virtual Environment

To do that, please consult the [conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) for doing so. 
After you have made your virtual env, make sure to install the tensorflow package after activating your conda virtual env with the appropriate python interpreter. Open Jupyter Notebook and look for an option to select that virtual env, and you are good to go.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when using pip to install Tensorflow 2. Install Tensorflow 2 using CONDA instead. Conda installs all the dependencies for Tensorflow 2 including the Nvidia CUDNN modules needed for GPU operation. As noted in the earlier answer use Anaconda to create a virtual environment then use conda to install Tensorflow into that environment